# Defining a bijection between a set and its equivalence relation

Tags: logic

> Suppose $f: A \to B$ is surjective. Define $R$ an equivalence relation
> (obvious) on $A$ by $a R b$ if $f(a) = f(b)$. Prove that there is a
> bijection between the set of equivalence classes (Say E) and $B$.

## approach:

Let $E = \{ [x] : x \in A \}$ where $[x] = \{ y : f(y) = f(x) \}$. This is given. We can see that $g:E\rightarrow B$ can be defined as $g([x]) = f(x)$.

if $g([x]) = g([y]) $, then $f(x) = f(y)$. Here I get stuck to prove $[x]=[y]$.

Can we argue as follow: Since $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x \in [y]$ but we also know that $y \in [y]$ and $y \in [x]$ since equivalence classes are disjoint then $[y]=[x]$ is forced to occur. And so injectivity follow:

As for surjectivity, pick any $b \in B$ and we know (f surjective) there is some $x \in A$ so that $b = f(x)$ but for every $x \in A$ we can always find $[x] \in E$. so surjectivity follow.

Where I am stuck and.I need guidance is in proving the $g$ is well defined.

Comment: Given that $f(x) = f(y)$, we know $xRy$ so that $[x]$ and $[y]$ define the same exact equivalence class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have can be cleaned up a bit, but it’s basically correct. It would be best to start by verifying that $g$ is well-defined, but that is clear: if $[x]=[y]$, then $x\,R\,y$, so $f(x)=f(y)$, and therefore $g([x])=g([y])$.

Then you can go on to show, pretty much as you did, that $g$ is injective: if $g([x])=g([y])$, then $f(x)=f(y)$ by the definition of $g$, so $x\in[y]$, but we also know that $x\in[x]$, so $[x]\cap[y]\ne\varnothing$, and therefore $[x]=[y]$. Depending on how much you’ve already done with equivalence relations, this might be overkill: you might be able to say directly that $x\,R\,y$, since $f(x)=f(y)$, and therefore $[x]=[y]$.

And finally you can show, again pretty much as you did, that $g$ is surjective: $f$ is surjective, so for any $b\in B$ there is an $x\in A$ such that $b=f(x)=g([x])$.

Comment: Thanks so much profesor!

Comment: @James: You're welcome!